# @ModelAttribute confusing

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Controller class that have login functionality. When I enter username and password and press submit, it will call this controller and store customer infor in the session. But one thing make me confusing is the @ModelAttribute

````
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("customer")
public class LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    CustomerService customService;
    
    @ModelAttribute("customer")
    public Customer getCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer customer) {
        Customer c = customService.getCustomer(customer.getUsername(), customer.getPassword());
        
        return c;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/login")
    public String submitLoginForm( Model model) {
        
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    
}```
````

I will use the @ModelAttribute Customer customer to store username and password I have inputted and use Customer c to store all information I got from customService and store it to the session. But the session store the Customer customer instead.

If I change the argument like this. It work normally

```
public Customer getCustomer(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) {
        Customer c = customService.getCustomer(username, password);
        
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: @FahimazazBhanej  I am working on a Spring Boot project. The Controller above will take care of login functionality. I will input username and password on login page. If login success, the index page will display fullname of the customer

Answer (score 0):

Your result might be vary due to @ModelAttribute

```
@ModelAttribute("customer")
public Customer getCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer customer) {
    Customer c = customService.getCustomer(customer.getUsername(), customer.getPassword()); 
    return c;
}
```

It's similar to:

```
@ModelAttribute

    public void initCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer customer,Model model) {
        Customer c = customService.getCustomer(customer.getUsername(), customer.getPassword()); 
        model.addAttribute("customer",c);
    }
```

initCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer customer,...)
The customer instance above is resolved as follows

- From the model if already added via Model.
- From the HTTP session via @SessionAttributes.
- From a URI path variable passed through a Converter (example below).
- From the invocation of a default constructor.
- From the invocation of a "primary constructor" with arguments matching to Servlet request parameters;
  argument names are determined via JavaBeans @ConstructorProperties
  or via runtime-retained parameter names in the bytecode.

As you can see, with first call, parameter values will be assigned to Customer customer...

But later call, session attributes is used with priority.

PS: your code might get a lot confusion. Please refer:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation